# Foundation - Interchange - other than html

Tags: javascript, ajax, zurb-foundation, foundation-interchange

I'm using [Foundation Interchange](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html) to dynamically load content into my page. It work's great with html files.
BUT: **How to use it to load other file-formats, concretely *.tpl* in my case.**

This works fine:

```
<div data-interchange="[{link file='frontend/index/sliderSMALL.html'}, (small)], [{link file='frontend/index/sliderBIG.html'}, (medium)]">
</div>
```

This does not work (tpl instead of html):

```
<div data-interchange="[{link file='frontend/index/sliderSMALL.tpl'}, (small)], [{link file='frontend/index/sliderBIG.tpl'}, (medium)]">
</div>
```

Just nothing happens. The tpl-files are not getting loaded.
An idea anybody?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [lazySizes include plugin](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/tree/gh-pages/plugins/include) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Interchange was designed to work with HTML partials and images extensions. Don't think it's set up to do TPL.